# Unable to work Cloud Code httpRequest HEAD method

Tags: parse-platform

Not sure if I'm doing this wrong but I want to make a cloud code httpRequest to validate URLs. I wanted to use the HEAD method and save on some data traffic but specifying HEAD seems to do exactly the same as a GET... seems like I'm getting the full body as well.

```
Parse.Cloud.define('validateURL', function(request, response) {
  var params = request.params;
  var url = params.url;

Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
    url: url,
    followRedirects: true,
    method: 'HEAD'
}).then(function(httpResponse) {

    // Redundant
    var httpObject = {
        buffer: httpResponse.buffer,
        cookies: httpResponse.cookies,
        data: httpResponse.data,
        headers: httpResponse.headers,
        status: httpResponse.status,
        text: httpResponse.text
    };

    response.success(httpObject);
}, function(error) {
    response.error(error.message);
});
```

});

I guess the question is, is this my problem or Parse.com's problem (or both or neither?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your httpRequest looks correct. You might want to [file a bug report](https://parse.com/help#report).

Comment: Thanks again Hector, will do. Still loving that Parse.com t-shirt and hoping you guys come back to NYC for another event. :-)